# How to model connection between tables?

Tags: python, armature

I'm very new to Blender and I try to model a database (tables and connections between them), but I'm having problems with the connections. What's the "easiest" way to create those lines? A visual representation of what I'm talking about (replace the "red line" with the "blue line", so the 1st table is connected to the 4th one without crossing the 2nd table):

[image]

I'm creating the model by creating an .obj file in python then import it in Blender. Plus Kudos if you can show me a code for this problem, because currently I'm just creating a cube between the tables (the 4-4 vertices is at the center of the tables), but it's "aligned" only on the Y axis (if I rotate the connected table around the other table, making it aligned on the X axis, the cube becomes a plain because of the vertices' coordinates).

I know/think I have to use armatures, but I couldn't make it to work.

Thanks for the hints/help!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "connection", ho should it appear? a red line? should it be animated when columns change height or position?

Comment: Sorry for the misleading "example", no, it doesn't have to be red (it's really not important, though I was thinking making the lines with cubes or cylinder), I just tried to highlight one connection from the image.

So the goal is to be able to "grab" the line, and move a little bit. The line should also follow both tables, so if I move one of the tables, the line should "stick" to it.

Comment: Definitely use curves, best to use a Bezier in this instance I'd say

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/41957/26640

Comment: For the python answer, look at the script made for [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26541/935)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One rough way could be using two empties for every "connection" shape, each hooked at one of the shape ends. Ten set a "copy location" constraint for each empty to its "column", it works like this:

[image]

Edit:
as you noted, the shape of the mesh (cylinder above but also cube has same issue) is stretched by its movement.

I found another way that seems to work without this issue: using a a curve to make the connection and a bezier circle to give it a "solid" shape:

[image]

It is made much like above but you create a hook to a new empty selecting one of the curve (2 control points, shape straightened before, and set to handle type "vector") end, then using again <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to make the hook menu appear, then selecting "new empty object".

[image]

As above, the empties have "copy location" constraints to each cube, but this time the "connection bar" is not stretched anymore, whatever the columns movement...

[image]

Of course it works also with scaling (here using a convenient transform pivot mode: cursor)

[image]

note: if you prefer a "squared" connector, just model the bezier circle to a square shape (or whatever), the connector profile is immediately updated

edit2: 
since you are missing some step, I tried a complete workflow (I hope it's not too long for this site):

start with the two "columns"

[image]

then in top view, place the cursor between them, and add a bezier

[image]

you will get this
[image]

edit the bezier 
[image]

select both control points and scale them to zero over Y axis with <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>

(this will make the bezier a straight line)

[image]

then in object mode rotate 90° over Z with <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>90</kbd>

[image]

note: here I also edited the bezier to have identical and symmetrical handles (it could be not necessary...), and then made both control points as "vector": select both, press <kbd>V</kbd> then choose "vector". This is needed.

[image]

now in front view you see

[image]

or (object mode):

[image]

now you need to add a hook to a new empty where each control point is, so select one of them, and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> and choose "hook to new empty object"

[image]

you'll get this

[image]

repeat for the other control point: now you have two empties hooked bt each bezier's control point

[image]

select one empty, and add a "copy location" constraint

[image]

with one cube as target

[image]

as you see instantly the empty copies the right cube position (object origin), and the bezier's control point follows (hooked to the empty)

[image]

now do the same for the other empty

[image]

as you see this is already working... but the connector is "invisible", because it's just a curve...

[image]

you need to bevel this curve with another "curve", so add a "bezier circle" in top view

[image]

you get this

[image]

if you set this object as bevel object of the "connector" bezier

[image]

the "connector" become solid, a visible cylinder shape

[image]

since it's quite big, scale the original bezier circle to your taste

[image]

and now is prettier

[image]

should you wish a different bevel profile (eg: a square) you always need a curve object, so you could transform the bezier circle into a bezier square: in edit mode, press <kbd>V</kbd> and select "vector"

[image]

you'll get this

[image]

and as you see the connector is now squared!

[image]

Here is the test file:
[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Hm...maybe it's just the gif, but aren't the "lines" change their shape? One of my problems is it should keep it, so the lines don't look like a plane if you place the tables in a specific way but always look like a cube/cuboid, has the same width/depth always.

Comment: yes, true... perhaps there's a way...

Comment: I found another way, it seems better... edited the answer.

Comment: I've just read your edited answer and it looks great! I'm really new to Blender, so there are a few things I don't know hot to do (yet), but I'll accept your answer because it looks very promising, thank you very much!

Comment: OK, good. I edited it again and added step-by-step workflow to setup this, and also a test file: have fun!